# Can not Quit Android Studio on MAC OS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

I have a problem with my Android Studio for almost one year or more, and it is a permanent problem. Every Time I need to close Android Studio I have to force quit it.

I can not quit it by pressing on the "x" button or by pressing "Quit Android Studio".

That is what I tried so far:

1- I tried to update it to the latest version.

2- I tried to download the latest version and install it and import the settings from the previous version.

3- I tried to uninstall Android Studio and delete all its related folders except the SDK folder.

But all of that is not working. So Any help is much appreciated

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you ever look at log files? Try to start android studio from console and trace the console on quitting.

Comment: @SinanCeylan Thank you very much. I found that this strange behavior was because of a plugin I installed long time ago. Uninstalling it, the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

try do the step 2 again without importing the settings from the previous version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately. It doesn't work